# How to let the server receive JSON DATA

Tags: php, json

I can't understand why this code doesn't get the JSON data from the Blocktrail Payments API)

```
$DATA = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
```

The server keeps saying that everything is good, but I can't get any data and there are no errors, is there any option on the server for enabling `php://input`?

I've already used other JSON data from other servers, for example, the Google reCaptcha and it works fine.

I use CloudFlare but it's turned off so it can't be causing this problem,

Comment: Assuming this is hooked to some form? Is your form of type multipart/form-data?

Comment: Can you try sending the request to the Blocktrail Payments API using Postman and see if that receive JSON data back? https://www.getpostman.com/